# Encoding Swift string as escaped unicode?

Tags: swift, unicode

The API data field only supports ASCII encoding -- but I need to support Unicode (emoji, foreign characters, etc.)

I'd like to encode the user's text input as an escaped unicode string:

```
let textContainingUnicode = """
Let's go  in the .
  And some new lines.
"""

let result = textContainingUnicode.unicodeScalars.map { $0.escaped(asASCII: true)}
  .joined(separator: "")
  .replacingOccurrences(
    of: "\\\\u\\{(.+?(?=\\}))\\}", <- converting swift format \\u{****}
    with: "\\\\U$1",               <- into format python expects
    options: .regularExpression)
```

`result` here is `"Let\'s go \U0001F3CA in the \U0001F30A.\n  And some new lines."`

And on the server decoding with python:

`codecs.decode("Let\\'s go \\U0001F3CA in the \\U0001F30A.\\n  And some new lines.\n", 'unicode_escape')`

But this smells funny -- do i really need to do so much string manipulation in swift to get the escaped unicode? Are these formats not standardized across languages.

Comment: Why can’t you just send the original string to the server? Unicode itself is the “standardized format”.

Comment: It's a constraint of AWS: "User-defined metadata is a set of key-value pairs. Amazon S3 stores user-defined metadata keys in lowercase. Each key-value pair must conform to US-ASCII when you are using REST and to UTF-8 when you are using SOAP or browser-based uploads via POST." They don't use SOAP clients anymore, i could write my own i guess. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingMetadata.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use reduce in your collection and check if each character isASCII, if true return that character otherwise convert the special character to unicode:

**Swift 5.1 • Xcode 11**

```
extension Unicode.Scalar {
    var hexa: String { .init(value, radix: 16, uppercase: true) }
}
```

---

```
extension Character {
    var hexaValues: [String] {
        unicodeScalars
            .map(\.hexa)
            .map { #"\\U"# + repeatElement("0", count: 8-$0.count) + $0 }
    }
}
```

---

```
extension StringProtocol where Self: RangeReplaceableCollection {
    var asciiRepresentation: String { map { $0.isASCII ? .init($0) : $0.hexaValues.joined() }.joined() }
}
```

---

```
let textContainingUnicode = """
Let's go  in the .
  And some new lines.
"""

let asciiRepresentation = textContainingUnicode.asciiRepresentation
print(asciiRepresentation)  // "Let's go \\U0001F3CA in the \\U0001F30A.\n  And some new lines."
```

Comment: If you’re going to use Swift 5 you can use the new nonescaping string literals and get rid of some backslashes

Comment: thanks Leo -- kind of cool to go through the logic of creating a utf-8 string. i'll accept this answer, thanks for taking the time on it.

Comment: Nice!. Thanks Leo