# How to convert string to escaped unicode sequence in Swift

Tags: json, swift, string, unicode

For a project I need Swift generated JSON strings to match the ones created with PHP's json_encode() function. Aside from the key sorting, the only difference I've noticed is that Swift is creating JSON with full unicode characters while PHP converts them with escaped unicode sequences (literals) ex: \u00e9.

After hitting the documentation I believe Swift's JSONEncoder does not have an option to output with unicode escaped characters. So now I'm trying to convert the standard unicode JSON string to a unicode escaped string.

Is there a way to convert, let's say,

"normal_string_éçü_abcd"   to   "normal_string_\u00e9\u00e7\u00fc_abcd"

in Swift?

Comment: Would you solve your problem if you could modify the json_encode() output?  I think there are options you can specify for json_encode() in PHP, and one allows you to output unescaped unicode -  `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE`.  Here's a reference:  https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55621940/2303865 same code from the duplicate link, set uppercase to false and return `return $0 + "\\u" + repeatElement("0", count: 4-hexa.count) + hexa`

Comment: `extension StringProtocol where Self: RangeReplaceableCollection {
    var asciiRepresentation: SubSequence {
        reduce("") {
            if $1.isASCII { return $0 + String($1) }
            let hexa = $1.unicodeScalars
                .map { .init($0.value, radix: 16, uppercase: false) }
                .joined()
            return $0 + "\\u" + repeatElement("0", count: 4-hexa.count) + hexa
        }
    }
}`